# Careers displays prior title possible bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I go to our company page:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/thyssenkrupp-system-engineering?searchTerm=Thyssenkrupp

And hover over the section "Who you'll work with" I see this:

[image]

But when I go to my careers profile it says this:

[image]

Shouldnt it say "Supervisor Application Development" as that is my most recent and current title?

This appears to be a bug...

Also I would like to work on the careers system :)...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that had to do with how we were choosing which position from your profile is the current one. It was fixed a few days ago, but unfortunately at this time it requires that the company page be re-published to pick up the fix. That company page has been re-published and you should see the correct title in that section.